# Creating multi-ring buffers (donuts) on a feature collection GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, feature-collection, buffer

I have a large feature collection that I am creating a multi-ring buffer on using GEE. My problem is that the `.difference` algorithm only works on a feature and not a feature collection. I tried to flatten the feature collection but that is still not working. How can I do this?

See code snippet below

```
////A function to add buffer rings to the refugee sites, recommended buffer size 40-50km
var ROI_a=RefugSites.map(function(ft){return ft.buffer(10000)});
var ROI_b=RefugSites.map(function(ft){return ft.buffer(30000)}).flatten();
//trying to use the inner circle here to subtract it from the second buffer
var ROI_b=ROI_b.map(function (f){return f.difference(ROI_a)}); 

var ROI_c=RefugSites.map(function(ft){return ft.buffer(40000)});
//and to do the same thing here, for the third ring/donuts 
var ROI_c=ROI_c.map(function (f){return f.difference(ROI_b)});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can be done in a `Feature`, it can also be done in each `Feature` inside a `FeatureCollection` using the `map` function.

```
////A function to add buffer rings to the refugee sites, recommended buffer size 40-50km
var createDonut = function(feature, outer_size, inner_size) {
  var outer = feature.buffer(outer_size)
  var inner = feature.buffer(inner_size)
  return outer.difference(inner)
}

var inner_size = 10000
var outer_size = 30000

var ROI_c = RefugSites.map(function(ft){return createDonut(ft, outer_size, inner_size)});
Map.addLayer(ROI_c, {}, 'Donuts')
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e795c91e10e5a571a3357cea8f7f26b3

Comment: Got it. That worked out really well. I appreciate it, Rodrigo. I wasn't super familiar with GEE `function` but now I understand how to use them.